# Не могу запустить песню через ссылку discord bot

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py, youtube-dl

Для начала, я пытаюсь создать бота, который воспроизводит звук из Ютуб видео. При вызове команды и указания ссылки или названия видео, вылезает такая ошибка, при этом код работает, так как в чате высвечивается "Не удалось загрузить песню. Неправильный формат, попробуйте другое ключевое слово", как я сам и указал, что при неправильном использовании команды должно высвечиваться это сообщение, но я делаю все правильно, так что я в замешательстве.

```
Бот MFMF_bot#0269 запустился и может начать работать
[download] Downloading playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiu7DGltccM
[youtube:search] query "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiu7DGltccM": Downloading page 1
[youtube:search] playlist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiu7DGltccM: 
Downloading 1 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] eiu7DGltccM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video eiu7DGltccM because of --no-playlist  
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Сверху то что появляется у меня в терминале при использовании команды, а снизу сам код

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {"format": "bestaudio", "noplaylist": "True"}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options": "-vn"}
        self.vc = None

    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)["entries"][0]
            except Exception:
                return False
            return {"source": info["formats"][0]["url"], "title": info["title"]}
    
    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing=True
            m_url=self.music_queue[0][0]["source"]
            self.music_queue.pop(0)
            self.vc.play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing=False
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing=True
            m_url=self.music_queue[0][0]["source"]
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connect():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Я хз куда подключаться")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
            self.music_queue.pop(0)
            self.vc.play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing=False
    
    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p", "playing"], help="Воспроизводит выбранную музыку из ютуба")
    async def playm(self, ctx, *args):
        query=" ".join(args)
        voice_channel=ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Подключись к голосовому каналу")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song=self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Не удалось загрузить песню. Неправильный формат, попробуйте другое ключевое слово")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Песня добавлена в очередь")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Ставит на паузу воспроизводимую музыку")
    async def pausem(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
             self.is_playing = True
             self.is_paused = False
             self.vc.resume()
    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Возобновляет воспроизведение музыку поставленной на паузу")
    async def resumem(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()
    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Скипает песню воспроизводя следующую по списку")
    async def skipm(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)
    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Показывает в чате какие песни в очереди")
    async def queuem(self, ctx):
        retval = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if i > 4: break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]["title"] + "\n"
        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Музыки в очереди больше нету")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Очищащет весь список воспроизводимой музыки")
    async def clearm(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Плейлист очищен")
    
    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Бот уходит из голосового чата")
    async def leavem(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: Так для всех видео, или только для одного?

Comment: Для всех видео, при этом по идее должно работать и с поиском по какому то слову, но и это не работает

Answer (score 1):

**Вы можете попробовать выполнить команду в терминале:**

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

---

**Если это не поможет, то перейдите по директории:**

```
.../Python/Lib/site-packages
```

**И следуйте инструкциям по [ссылке](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31538)**